# Adafruit Pt100 temperature sensor

Tags: temperature, pt100

I want to connect 3 wire pt100 sensor with arduino uno, without using any amplifier or op-amp. What could be the circuit of the same?

Comment: you can connect anything, but whether it will be doing something useful is a different question. **for which purpose** do you want to connect the sensor, and *why* can't you use an amplifier?

Comment: You should **search** for a suitable circuit using Google. If you cannot find any that are **not** using an opamp then the obvious conclusion is that very likely no one does that (use a PT100 without opamp) as it is impractical, does not work well enough, etc. Also, figure out **why** the opamp is there in the first place. Hint: the change in behavior of the PT100 over temperature is so small that the ADC in an Arduino cannot detect that properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhVWUD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can connect it like that. It will not exceed the 1.0mA current recommended for a Pt100 element. The resolution will be about 15°C, which is useless for most applications but it meets your requested limitations and does respond to temperature, after a fashion.

If you **abuse** the element by reducing R1 to 499 ohms (10x the maximum current and thus 100x the recommended dissipation) you'll get about 2°C resolution but a **lot** of self-heating (read your sensor datasheet to calculate how much at whatever temperature) and dubious reliability.

---

Perhaps you can see why basically nobody does anything like this. There are microcontrollers that can work well with small signals but the Arduino does not contain one.

If you switched the 5V to a 499R resistor with a small MOSFET (p-channel) and operated at a very low duty cycle you could probably get this to work with reasonable results, but an op-amp would be a much more sensible answer.

Comment: Your last paragraph is interesting. I wouldn't have considered pulsing the device to keep the average power low and prevent self-heating. The pulsed +5 V feed could be taken directly from a GPIO output directly although the whole device may need calibration. Shouldn't R1 be 4.9k (5k total) and your 499R be 400R to give a 5:1 divider?

Comment: @Transistor You would want Rds(on) << R1 unless you intend to measure the voltage after the switch. That's pretty easy using something like an [AO3401](http://aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AO3401A.pdf) (0.06\$\Omega\$ @ 4.5V drive).  GPIO might be 50 or 100 ohms equivalent. The RTD resistance will change, of course, the actual precise value of R1 not that important provided it is a known value (there will be an equation or a look-up table to convert the ADC reading to temperature). Thanks for the comment.